# Select multiple tables using INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I have 3 tables:

Table: Files

| id | type | size | path | documentID | proofID | userID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | pdf | 100 | /document/something-1.pdf | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | pdf | 100 | /document/something-1.pdf | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | pdf | 100 | /document/something-2.pdf | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | pdf | 100 | /document/something-2.pdf | 2 | 1 | 1 |

Table : Documents

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Document |
| 2 | Document 2 |

Table : Proofs

| id | name | documentID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Something | 1 |
| 2 | Something | 1 |
| 3 | Something | 2 |

Expected results :

| document | proof | path |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Document | 2 | /document/something-1.pdf |
| Document 2 | 1 | /document/something-2.pdf |

- I want to select all documents uploaded by user 1 from table Files (userID: 1)
- Then select these documents name using documentID from table Documents, count how many proof it has

I have been trying something like :

```
SELECT
Documents.name as document, 
COUNT(files.proofID) as proof, 
files.path as path,
FROM files
INNER JOIN Documents ON files.documentID = Documents.id
INNER JOIN Proof ON files.proofID = Proof.id
WHERE files.userID = 1
```

this query give something like

| document | proof | path |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Document | 3 | /document/something-1.pdf |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this query

```sql
WITH files(id,type,size,path,docid,proofid,userid) AS ( VALUES
('1', 'pdf', '100', '/document/something-1.pdf', '1', '1', '1'),
('2', 'pdf', '100', '/document/something-1.pdf', '1', '2', '1'),
('3', 'pdf', '100', '/document/something-2.pdf', '2', '1', '2'),
('4', 'pdf', '100', '/document/something-2.pdf', '2', '1', '1')
), 
proofs(id,name,docid) AS (VALUES 
('1', 'Something', '1'), 
('2', 'Something', '1'), 
('3', 'Something', '2')
),
docs(id, name) AS (VALUES
('1','Document'),
('2','Document 2')
)
SELECT f.docid,d.name,count(p.docid) FROM files f INNER JOIN proofs p ON f.proofid=p.id INNER JOIN docs d ON d.id=f.docid WHERE userid='1' GROUP BY f.docid,d.name
```

the output of the query

```
docid   name    count
1   Document    2
2   Document 2  1
```

Comment: Document 1 has two proofs, the results of above query show 1 proof

Comment: ```docid | name | count
1 | Document | 2
2 | Document 2 | 1```